# Is there a way to toggle code in and out of live code for testing?

Tags: testing, coldfusion

I have a coldfusion website, and at one point we put in a log - whenever a certain type of code was run, that code was logged. Now we'd like to take it out, but still have the option of putting it back in, so we're planning on finding every time (there are probably hundreds) this code was logged and commenting out the logging code. This seems quite tedious to me and I was wondering if there's some sort of way to mark code as testing and automatically enable/disable it by changing the settings in one place... I think I've seen functionality like this in other languages. Is this possible in ColdFusion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I would handle this is by configuring some sort of global application variable (e.g. `doLogging`) that you can switch on and off and check when needed. If it is set to `true` then log, otherwise don't.

For example in `Application.cfc` you could set up this variable:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="Application" output="false">


 <cfset APPLICATION.doLogging= false />

 <cffunction name="onRequestStart" access="public" output="false"> 

  <cfif structKeyExists(URL, "toggleLogging")>
   <cfif APPLICATION.doLogging>
    <cfset APPLICATION.doLogging = false />
   <cfelse>
    <cfset APPLICATION.doLogging = true />
   </cfif>

  </cfif>

 </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

And then check for it where needed in your code:

```
<cfif APPLICATION.doLogging>
    <cflog file="foo" text="bar" />
</cfif>
```

You will have to change your existing code though to use this new method, but managing it in future would be easier.

Hope that helps!

EDIT: changed variable names to be more sensible and added an example of use.

Comment: I think this is a good idea, but I would wrap the cfif and cflog call inside of a CFC instead.

Comment: That's more or less what I was going to suggest, but I would avoid using a toggle parameter.  Use an explicit on or off state (eg url.doLogging = 1) so that you don't have to keep track of whether logging is on or off.

Comment: All fair points. The idea is the same but the implementation could be tidied up. In reality I would wrap this check and (possible) log in a custom tag because I hate the idea of referencing the APPLICATION scope directly in a CFC. I accept you could pass it in, but sometimes deep in code this can get very messy.

Comment: Ok, I think my answer said practically the same thing. Thing I don't get is: Why URL variable? How do you set that variable in URL scope in workflow? For example you have link to "About page" of your website example.com/aboutus, and, how do you set it?

Comment: @zarko in the query string example.com/aboutus?dologging=1

Answer (score 4):

Investigate [cftrace](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c00.html), which generates its own log, and is turned on and off from the ColdFusion admin. When turned off, ColdFusion ignores the tag.

Comment: Avoid cftrace by all possible means! It screws up remote calls, wsdls, coldfire and I can't even remember what else...

Comment: I'm assuming if it's turned on? But debugging in general produces this issue... can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the IsDebugMode() function which will return true if you have ColdFusion debugging on and false if it is off.

Comment: This is the approach I would use, personally, though the application-scoped variable suggested in another response would work, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ColdFusion 9.0.1 and you used custom logs, you can stop logging into those logs by pressing (stop) button in Administrator. Apart from that, I don't think there some debug/production option which could disable those when deployed. You could do massive search/replace with regexp in Eclipse and wrap cflog tag with cfif asking is it debug mode or production mode, and that you can set in application scope on app start.

cflog as far as I know uses log4j in background, possibly there's some hidden way to use log4j's functionalities from cfml.